# Control units of time series data for plot axis labeling

Tags: plotting, labeling, units

Using Mathmatica time series data:

```
dataPopulationMexico = 
  CountryData["Mexico", {{"Population"}, {1970, 2015}}];
dataPopulationCanada = 
  CountryData["Canada", {{"Population"}, {1970, 2015}}];
dataPopulationUS = 
  CountryData["UnitedStates", {{"Population"}, {1970, 2015}}];
```

If I generate a plot:

```
DateListPlot[{dataPopulationUS, dataPopulationCanada, 
  dataPopulationMexico}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {"United States", "Mexico", "Canada"}]
```

I get an axis with scientific notation on the Y:

[image]

I would much rather have the Y axis be in units of 1 million. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: `DateListPlot[{dataPopulationUS, dataPopulationCanada, 
  dataPopulationMexico}/10^6, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {"United States", "Mexico", "Canada"}]`? Then I'd just change the axis to read something like `Millions of People`.

Comment: The axes aren't $x$ and $y$ unless you define them as such. If you don't explicitly define $x = \mathrm{year}$ and $y = \mathrm{population}$, then please, just call them the horizontal and vertical axes, or ideally the abscissa and ordinate. (That people use $x$ and $y$ without giving any definitions is a persistent irritation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Fixed the legend so that the labels correspond to the correct data, caught by @m_goldberg's keen eye.

---

Using

```
 DateListPlot[{dataPopulationUS, dataPopulationCanada, dataPopulationMexico}/10^6, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Millions of People"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"United States", "Canada","Mexico"}]
```

results in

[image: plot output]

Comment: It should be `PlotLegends -> {"United States", "Canada", "Mexico"}`. Mexico has a much bigger and faster-growing population than Canada. Not your fault. OP got it wrong.